# How would I go about making a script for volume based candles?

Tags: pine-script

I'm new here and just had a quick question in regards to volume based candles.

I'm interested in attempting to write some code for volume based candles rather than time or tick based candles.

The objective more or less is to have candles that don't print until they hit a fixed value of say 50,000 and then a candle prints.

I know Tradovate and Ninja Trader have this feature built in, but I prefer using TOS and if I could find a wait to get that to work that'd be great.

I'm trying to use this to chart Supply and Demand zones in futures and feel that volume based candles will cut out some extra noise that using time based candles can't.

So now for the question. Is these possible in Pine Script ? I have no coding knowledge in Pine Script and really don't want to be chasing my own tail if this isn't do able. Any feedback or tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to write a script for TOS (Thinkscript) or Tradingview (Pinescript) platform?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to draw your own candles in pine, you won't be able to escape time, but you can hold the candle values however long you desire.   I would probably use the array function to do what you want.